# How to make Odoo website search in header?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

I am trying to add search input in Header Area in Odoo 10 Website. It works when visit /Shop page, but it gives Internal Error 500, on other pages.

My code in Main Layout is,

```
<t t-call="website_sale.search" />
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2TZf.jpg)

How can I overcome this problem and make search option available from any page?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about v10, but in v14 you can remove a line in website_sale.search as a sort of quick workaround.

Comment or remove this line to avoid 500 error:

```
<t t-set="action" t-value="keep('/shop'+ ('/category/'+slug(category)) if category else None, search=0)"/>
```

It will probably look something like this in a module:

```
<template id="name_of_the_id" inherit_id="website_sale.search">
    <xpath expr="//t/t/t[1]" position="replace">
    </xpath>
</template>
```